# Список IP бесплатных прокси серверов

Tags: java, ip, proxy

Для парсера сайтов ищу нормально (ну или относительно нормально) работающие прокси для обхода блокировки.
В интернете полно ресурсов, которые выкладывают ip прокси серверов, но на практике максимум 10-20 % из них работают. Поделитесь что вы используете - ресурсы или какие есть реально рабочие API.

Comment: На практике прокся, дохлая сегодня, оживает завтра - и наоборот.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я обычно работаю с другой стороны - разрабатываю механизмы защиты. И первое, что я делаю - это блокировка публичных прокси, в том числе платных, публичных VPN-сервисов, анонимайзеров и выходных нод TOR. Проще говоря, распарсить некоторые сайты вы можете только в том случае, если в несколько раз богаче их владельцев и умнее разработчиков защиты.

Comment: тут коллели пару десятков модемов покругу гоняют)

Comment: @eri подобных атак примерно 0.0001% от общего числа, но и на них есть управа, если заказчик готов платить за интеллектуальную систему анализа запросов. При должном уровне инвестиций обнаружить и забанить можно даже кликфермы.